# Why my pytorch test script got "IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)" error?

Tags: pytorch, sentence-transformers

The following code runs into `"IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)"` exception that is thrown from the line `similarity = torch.cosine_similarity(embeddings1, embeddings2)`. Any insights on why we get this error. The default value of `dim` parameter for `torch.cosine_similarity` is 1. Why does torch expect `[-1, 0]` ?

```
import torch
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

# Load the sentence transformer model
model = SentenceTransformer("all-mpnet-base-v2")

# Encode two sentences
sentence1 = "The cat sat on the mat."
sentence2 = "The dog ate the bone."
embeddings1 = torch.from_numpy(model.encode(sentence1))
embeddings2 = torch.from_numpy(model.encode(sentence2))

# Calculate the cosine similarity between the two embeddings
similarity = torch.cosine_similarity(embeddings1, embeddings2)
print(similarity)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you (correctly) that with your input shape, the only valid values for `dim` are 0 or 1, so just fix your code with `similarity = torch.cosine_similarity(embeddings1, embeddings2, dim=0)`.

I guess the default for `dim = 1` is the case where you want to find the similarity for a batch of data, which is really the standard case for most pytorch users.

Edit to clarify what torch.cosine_similarity does (see also the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineSimilarity.html)): One dimension along a tensor is interpreted as a vector, cosine similarity is calculated and therefore that dimension gets reduced to a scalar value. Because the "tensor" in this example is 1D, the only allowable input for `dim` is 0 (first dimension) or -1 (last valid dimension, i.e., same as 0 in this example).

Comment: why `dim=1` do not work? what does `dim` mean in the context of `torch.cosin_similarity`?

Comment: I updated my answer with a brief explanation.